# Google tracking code not counting

Tags: google-analytics

I just installed Google Analytics code in a new web site. The site has a single page. I put the unmodified code wight before the  tag:
http://visualbioinformatics.com

I uploaded the page but Analytics won't track any visitors (me). I am looking in Real-Time section. I pressed Control+U in Firefox to see the source code of the page and the tracking JS code is there.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-3648000-11', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
</head>
```

Also the tracking code generator page (in Google Analytics) says: "Last checked: May 12, 2015 1:58:57 AM PDT *[!now!]*
The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page. For Analytics to function, you or your web administrator must add the code to each page of your website"

Firebug shows no errors in my web page.

Why cannot google detect the code?

Comment: It can take up to 72 hours for new sites to start recording data.

Comment: But 'Real time' Analytics is not recording. Is 'real time'... right?

Comment: then what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Vote close: This question does not appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using "One Million Clicks fake web traffic generator" with proxies and now Google Analytics started to show visitors in 'Real time' stats. It seems that Google Real Time analytic counted me once then ignored me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same with Firefox setting [Tracking Protection](http://monica-at-mozilla.blogspot.com.au/2014/11/tracking-protection-in-firefox.html) enabled.
When this is disabled everything works fine for me.
(Firefox 39.0)

Comment: interesting to know but it is not my case